# String length limitation in PrintPreviewDialog call to PrintDocument.PrintPage

Tags: c#, winforms, printing

Using VS Community 2017 with .NET Framework 4.6.

The following code was taken from MS documentation and works fine for  printing to a printer but has a limitation in PrintPreviewDialog  calls.

```
string text;
string ToPrint;
private void PrintDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    int charactersOnPage = 0;
    int linesPerPage = 0;

    // Sets the value of charactersOnPage to the number of characters
    // of stringToPrint that will fit within the bounds of the page.
    e.Graphics.MeasureString(ToPrint, this.Font,
        e.MarginBounds.Size, StringFormat.GenericTypographic,
        out charactersOnPage, out linesPerPage);
    // Draws the string within the bounds of the page.
    e.Graphics.DrawString(ToPrint, this.Font, Brushes.Black,
        e.MarginBounds, StringFormat.GenericTypographic);

    // Remove the portion of the string that has been printed.
    ToPrint = ToPrint.Substring(charactersOnPage);

    // Check to see if more pages are to be printed.
    e.HasMorePages = (ToPrint.Length > 0);

    // If there are no more pages, reset the string to be printed.
    if (!e.HasMorePages)
        ToPrint = text;
}
```

After experimenting I found that e.Graphics.DrawString produces blank print preview pages if 'ToPrint' string is greater than 32490 characters long.

Does anyone know why this is? Is there some setting or option that I'm missing?

Thanks

Comment: It could be related to the size (pixels) and font type of the string you want to print.

Comment: You are printing the entire contents of ToPrint.  Don't do that.  SubString out the part you want to print and then try drawing that.